# Парсинг массива

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Есть массив с данными:**

```
[66.359206 61.524034 77.9281 191.712005615234, 66.358962 61.523997 78.4192 191.725997924805, 66.358717 61.523961 78.9671 191.738998413086]
```

**Необходимо получить только эти значения на протяжение всего массива (записей много):**

```
77.9281 191.712005615234,
78.4192 191.725997924805,
78.9671 191.738998413086
```

**Пробовал так, результат не подходит, так как все данные смешиваются.**

```py
import re
re.split( r'\s+|,\s*', text)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать.

Comment: 3 и 4 значение из каждой четвёрки, что ли?

Comment: А как понять какие данные нужно получить? Напишите в вопросе по какому принципу берем данные из массива

Comment: @Akina да именно так

Comment: @gil9red у меня есть файл JSON, в нем данный массив. Необходимо получить из [66.359206 61.524034 77.9281 191.712005615234,] только [77.9281 191.712005615234], а далее сверять их с данными из другого файла(правда там уже XML и как обращаться к элементам известно)
Что значит по какому принципу, не совсем понимаю(

Comment: По какому принципу означает откуда мы знаем, что брать нужно эти два значения, а не соседние.

Comment: @Эникейщик аа, 1 и 2 элементы - долгота и широта, 3 - 4 элементы - протяженность кривой. Вот последнее и надо

Comment: SPLIT по запятой, потом каждый элемент SPLIT по пробелу и взять 3 и 4 элементы.

Comment: @Marhell, странный массив json... Там должны быть запятые. Или этот массив в json в виде строки?

Comment: @gil9red похоже вы правы, [
    "68.957667 60.987031 14.7522 11.0590000152588, 68.957406 60.98701 14.7083 11.0729999542236" ]

Comment: @Akina 
def divideDataFile(list_track):
    dividePoint = list_track.split(',')
    for i in dividePoint:
        print(i.split())
а как обратиться именно к 3 и 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример парсинга строки с массивом через регулярные выражения и перебора каждой четверки массива с выводом 3 и 4 значения каждой четверки:

```
import re

text = "[66.359206 61.524034 77.9281 191.712005615234, 66.358962 61.523997 78.4192 191.725997924805, 66.358717 61.523961 78.9671 191.738998413086]"
items = re.findall('\d+\.\d+', text)
print(items)
# ['66.359206', '61.524034', '77.9281', '191.712005615234', '66.358962', '61.523997', '78.4192', '191.725997924805', '66.358717', '61.523961', '78.9671', '191.738998413086']

for i in range(0, len(items), 4):
    print(items[i + 2], items[i + 3])
# 77.9281 191.712005615234
# 78.4192 191.725997924805
# 78.9671 191.738998413086
```

Comment: вообще, два сплита были бы надежней. В таких странных данных может быть и 77, а не 77.0

Comment: @splash58, все может быть, нужно тестировать. А так, вы предлагаете что-то вроде: `items = text[1:-1].split()`?

Comment: либо в re `'\d+\.?\d+?',  либо text[1:-1].split(',') и для каждого split() и брать 3 и 4